# httpd не находит mod_authn_alias.so

Tags: apache, centos, vesta

Начну с предистории.
Я устанавливал vesta на сервер, проблем не было.
После установки он попытался запуститься но заругался на apache и потух.

Запустив команду

```
httpd -t
```

Получил такой ответ

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 39 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authn_alias.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_alias.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Пытался найти этот файл командой

```
find / -type f -name mod_authn_alias.so
```

и вручную вписать путь для файла тут **httpd.conf**, но с горечью понял что его нету вообще. Как можно подгрузить или что лучше сделать?

Comment: а что такое «vesta»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin http://vestacp.com

Comment: *bash vst-install.sh* — нда уж… «скачать без регистрации и эсэмэс». // так вы файл-то приложите, чтоб можно было поточнее вам подсказать, какие строки комментировать?

Comment: кстати, посмотрел на «поддерживаемые» версии дистрибутивов. вероятно, код привязан к каким-то (относительно) старым версиям программ. например, к apache версии не выше 2.2. // у вас что с версией дистрибутива?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я понимаю что скорее всего проблема в этом. У меня CentOS 7. Смотрел тут https://vestacp.com/roadmap/ есть поддержка моей ос. Но как вытащить именно эту версию не знаю

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте закомментировать эту 39-ю строку файла `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` (поставив символ `#` в начало строки).

если я правильно понимаю, что написано в [этом сообщении об ошибке](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=903616), это имеет отношение и к вашему случаю.

Comment: Что-то не то. httpd: Syntax error on line 42 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authn_default.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_default.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Думаю проблему нужно менять другим путем

Comment: ну, видимо, и 42-ю надо закомментировать. а, возможно, блок между ними — это я просто пытаюсь догадаться. но правильнее совет можно будет дать, если вы приложите это самый файл к вопросу.

Comment: Вы скорее всего правы на счет разных версий программ. настройки не подходят просто. тут наверное или устанавливать другую версию(найти я ее не могу). или другую систему(пока не знаю какую)